# How to remove the degrees celsius symbol from a string (java)

Tags: java, temperature, replaceall

I've been trying to remove the degree Celsius symbol from the following string for a few hours now. I've looked at prior posts and I see that /u2103 is the unicode representation for it. Despite trying to remove that string, I've still had no luck. Here's what I have now:

```
String temp = "Technology=Li-poly;Temperature=23.0 <degree symbol>C;Voltage=3835";
StringBuilder filtered = new StringBuilder(temp.length()); 
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
char test = temp.charAt(i);
if (test >= 0x20 && test <= 0x7e) {
    filtered.append(test);
}
}

temp = filtered.toString();

temp.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

The resulting string looks like this:
Technology=Li-poly;Temperature=**23.0 C**;

I've also tried

```
temp.replaceAll("\\u2103", "");
temp.replaceChar((char)0x2103, ' ');
```

But none of this works.

My current problem is that the function to filter the string leaves a blank space but the call to replaceAll(" ", "%20") doesn't seem to recognize that particular space. ReplaceAll will replace other spaces with %20.

Comment: Are you sure it's `\u2103` and not `\u00B0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
temp.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

You're calling `replaceAll` but never using the result. Strings are immutable - any method which *looks* like it's changing the content is actually *returning* the different string as a result. You want:

```
temp = temp.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Having said that, it's not clear why you're trying to replace the space at all, nor what's wrong with your resulting string.

You've got the same problem with your other `temp.replaceAll` and `temp.replaceChar` calls.

Your attempt to replace the character directly would also fail as you're escaping the backslash - you really want:

```
temp = temp.replace("\u2103", "");
```

Note the use of `replace` instead of `replaceAll` - the latter uses regular expressions, which there's no need to use at all here.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I didn't need the double backslash and I should have been using replace, not replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could leverage the [Character.isWhiteSpace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) function.